# Which Null Exception to throw?

Tags: c#, exception

Consider the following class and method:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public MyDtoChild Child {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public void ProcessDto(MyDto myDto)
{
    if(myDto == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("myDto");
    this.CheckSomething(myDto.Child.ChildProperty);
}
```

If called with a `MyDto` with a null `Child` left to it's own devices this will throw a `NullReferenceException` which can be extremely  difficult to diagnose in more complex methods.

Typically I throw an `ArgumentNullException` at the start of the method if `myDto` is null but what is the appropriate exception to throw if `myDto.Children` is null? An `ArgumentNullException`? A `NullReferenceException`? A custom exception?

Comment: You could guarantee that `MyDto.Child` will never be null by using a `readonly` modifier on its backing field, assuming that `MyDto` will own the field's value.

Comment: @KamilT simply because it's just taken me several hours to track down where this particular null ref is coming and I'd like to make it more robust for future developers.

Comment: Is it OK for child to be `null` in other parts of your system or its an exceptional case?

Comment: You could try using code contracts too

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy this particular case - it happens to be coming from EF so I'm loathed to mess with the properties of the entity. I'm just aid any future trouble shooting

Comment: @Liath one more question - is it program logic error which should break all further computation, or you have some workaround of this case (e.g. you can use some default value for ChildProperty)? Also does it happen often or not?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks for your interest and help. It's an optional parameter which may or may not be loaded for sake of efficiency but is required for this method to function. It's quite possible it won't be loaded. In fact my fix to the issue was simply to load it!

Comment: @Liath hmm.. so further program execution is not possible if child is not loaded?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, well the operation would fail - the program would survive but you'd have a cranky user

Comment: @Liath so, it's not data problem - its program logic problem?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the data is invalid for that method. I'm leaning towards ArgumentException myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by the previous answers, it should not be an `ArgumentNullException` since the argument `myDTO` is not NULL.
To me it makes more sense to throw an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since the argument passed to the method did not meet the requirements (you expect Children to not be null). Moreover, your situation fits the ArgumentException's description:

> ArgumentException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one
>   of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of
>   the called method.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who's given suggestions. I'm selecting this as the answer as it confirms @Silvermind 's comment about not raising null refs and gives a good level of description why.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not an `ArgumentNullException`. If you can access the property Children of your myDto, this means that myDto, which is the **argument**, is *not null*. Thus, no ArgumentNullException as the myDto itself is *not null*.

As you suggested you can throw a `NullReferenceException` and add your own message so you know where this comes from and explain it nicely. This is completely logic because the **reference** to the property you want to use is *null*.

As @Silvermind mentioned, the NullReferenceException should not be used. Instead you have other options such as the `ArgumentException` or the `InvalidOperationException`. Another option would be to create your own exception-type that derives from the `Exception` class.

Example:

```
public class ChildNullException: Exception
{
    public ChildNullException() { }

    public ChildNullException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public ChildNullException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not raise [reserved exception types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx)  such as `NullReferenceException`. Use `InvalidOperationException` with an appropriate message.

Comment: @Silvermind thanks for mentioning, didn't know this! :) I've updated my answer acoordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If the argument is non-null but somehow invalid, you should throw an `ArgumentException`:

```
if(myDto == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("myDto");
if(myDto.Child == null) throw new ArgumentException("Property Child must not be null.", "myDto");
```

Comment: I think this is the better solution.  `ArgumentNullException` expects a parameter that identifies the parameter by name that was null.  `ArgumentException` is more generic in that you give it a message which should identify the problem (with the child property), and allow you to identify which root parameter it pertained to.

Answer (score 3):

Child of your argument is not your argument, so `ArgumentNullException` is not appropriate here. I think the best way will be to throw `NullReferenceException` with an explanation message.

Comment: Do not raise [reserved exception types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx)  such as `NullReferenceException`. Use `InvalidOperationException` with an appropriate message.

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation I see that this is a program logic error, not data problem. You either load child entity before calling this method, and everything works fine, or you don't load child and this logic cannot be executed. So, it makes no sense to throw some custom exception here, because after you fix problem first time, problem will not happen again. Just see stack trace of exception, fix program logic and forget about this case. Use global exception handler for that.